# Nonblocking sockets

Tags: c, sockets

I am looking for a way to do more flexible socket communication.

Code form external link works just fine but the issue is that when I run 2 or more instances of "client" program second and next instance must wait till previous instance finish its communication with "server". How can I fix it?

ps sorry for my poor english and external link but I have no idea how to add code here which is correctly indented etc.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/38rxvghroqaxuci/mix.c?dl=0

Best regards.

**edit** that's the way you can post code

server

```
// call socket()
// call bind()    
// call listen()
while (1)   
  {
    incomming_connection = accept(uds_dispacher_fd, (struct sockaddr     *)&uds_peer_config, &uds_peer_config_len);

    while ( (no_of_bytes_read=recv(incomming_connection, uds_input_buffer, UDS_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) != 0 )
    {
      if (uds_input_buffer[no_of_bytes_read-2] == '\n')
      {
        switch (uds_input_buffer[0])
        {
          case SOME_VARIABLE:
            strcpy(buffer, "Hello");
            break;
          default:
            strcpy(buffer, "Wut");
        }
      }
      send(incomming_connection, buffer, strlen(uds_output_buffer),0);
    }
  }
```

client code:

```
int client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
...
int con = connect(client, (struct sockaddr*) &my_addr, sizeof my_addr); 
...
for (int i =0;i<10; ++i)
{
    send(client, buffer2, 3, 0);  
    recv(client, buffer1, 256, 0); 
    puts(buffer1);
    usleep(500000);
}
```

Comment: See [ask] and [tour], which should help with how to format questions/comments.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. I've edited your question and posted the code directly. Please look at it so that you know the next time

Comment: Your server has to handle the connections concurrently; essentially, there are three common ways for that: 1) Fork a process per connection after `accept()`ing one. 2) Use multithreading and one thread per connection. 3) Use `select()`, `poll()` or `epoll()` to create an event-based single-threaded server. Probably the first method is the easiest.

Comment: when posting code, indent all lines by 4 spaces